# FIltering for Largest Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query that will return the highest instance of Site per Operon. Basically each operon can have many sites, but each site has a score. I want to filter the return so that rather than having a given operon listed multiple times (once for each site) it will be listed only once with the highest site.

What I have below seems to return the correct results but it is fairly slow and I wanted to see if there was a faster way of doing this or not.

Sorry if this isn't very clear, MySQL is a totally new world for me and I'm not sure if I'm posing the question in a sensible way.

```
select `g`.`id`       AS `ID`, 
   `g`.`Name`     AS `GENE`,
   `o`.`id`       AS `OPID`,
   `os`.`site`    AS `BSID`,
   `s`.`Sequence` AS `SITE`,
   `s`.`Score`    AS `SCORE`

from(((( 
          `METAGENO`.`GENE`        `g` )
     join `METAGENO`.`OPERON`      `o` )
     join `METAGENO`.`OPERON_SITE` `os`)
     join `METAGENO`.`SITE`        `s` )

    where(
          (`o` .`id`     = `g` .`Operon`)
       and(`os`.`operon` = `o` .`id`    )
       and(`s` .`id`     = `os`.`site`  
       and(`s` .`Score`  = (select max(`s2`.`Score`)
                                from(`METAGENO`.`SITE` `s2`)
                                where(`s2`.`id` = `os`.`site`))))) GROUP BY `o`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
GREATEST()
```

For two or more arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating an inline view that calculates all the maxscore for all id and then join.

```
Select `g`.`id`       AS `ID`, 
   `g`.`Name`     AS `GENE`,
   `o`.`id`       AS `OPID`,
   `os`.`site`    AS `BSID`,
   `s`.`Sequence` AS `SITE`,
   `s`.`Score`    AS `SCORE`

from(((( 
          `METAGENO`.`GENE`        `g` )
     join `METAGENO`.`OPERON`      `o` )
     join `METAGENO`.`OPERON_SITE` `os`)
     join `METAGENO`.`SITE`        `s` )

     INNER JOIN (select max(`s2`.`Score`) as maxScore, `s2`.`id`
                 from `METAGENO`.`SITE` `s2`
                 group by `s2`.`id`) maxScore
     ON  s.Score = maxScore.Score
         AND os.site = maxScore.id

    where(
          (`o` .`id`     = `g` .`Operon`)
       and(`os`.`operon` = `o` .`id`    )
       and(`s` .`id`     = `os`.`site`  ))
```

Comment: I have also tried changing `GROUP BY `op`.`id`` to `GROUP BY `op`.`id` HAVING MAX(`s`.`Score)` This works as well.